# Django displaying blog posts on different pages

Tags: python, django, url, view, blogs

I'm rather new to Django and I've been following a tutorial on building a simple blog application. My application works fine so far (using Django 1.8.6). Here are my urls.py, views.py and models.py:

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls', namespace='blog', app_name='blog')),
```

blog/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^$', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
   url(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/(?P<day>\d{2})/'\
       r'(?P<post>[-\w]+)/$',
       views.post_detail,
       name='post_detail'),
    url(r'^tag/(?P<tag_slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.post_list,
       name='post_list_by_tag'),    
]
```

blog/views.py

```
def post_list(request, tag_slug=None):
    object_list = Post.published.all()
    tag = None
    if tag_slug:
        tag = get_object_or_404(Tag, slug=tag_slug) 
        object_list = object_list.filter(tags__in=[tag])
    return render(request,
                 'blog/post/list.html',
                 {
                 'posts': posts,
                 'tag': tag
                 })


def post_detail(request, year, month, day, post):
   post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=post,
                                  status='published',
                                  publish__year=year,
                                  publish__month=month,
                                  publish__day=day)
   post_tags_ids = post.tags.values_list('id', flat=True)
   similar_posts = Post.published.filter(tags__in=post_tags_ids)\
                                 .exclude(id=post.id)
   similar_posts = similar_posts.annotate(same_tags=Count('tags'))\
                               .order_by('-same_tags','-publish')[:4]
   return render(request,
                 'blog/post/detail.html',
                 {'post': post,
                 'similar_posts': similar_posts})
```

blog/models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
       ('draft', 'Draft'),
       ('published', 'Published'),
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250,
                           unique_for_date='publish')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,
                              related_name='blog_posts', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField()
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10,
                             choices=STATUS_CHOICES,
                             default='published')
    tags = TaggableManager()

    class Meta:
       ordering = ('-publish',)
    def __str__(self):
       return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
           return reverse('blog:post_detail',
                          args=[self.publish.year,
                                self.publish.strftime('%m'),
                                self.publish.strftime('%d'),
                                self.slug])


    objects = models.Manager() # The default manager.
    published = PublishedManager() # Our custom manager.
```

Now I would like to create 4 pages and each blog post should be displayed on one of those pages based on author's choice. I would like to have a custom template for my pages that allows me to add other main page content above the blog posts. My idea was to create a "pages" application with a template that is extended by the blog template. In the blog model I would implement a "pagedisplay" field where the author in the cms can select the page on which he wants the post displayed.
So in essence instead of displaying all posts on the www.example.com/blog page and linking to them from there, I would like to distribute them over multiple pages based on choice by the author.
In the end, the url should look somewhat like this for individual posts.

```
 www.example.com/page2/2017/12/30/post1/
```

Whereas

```
 www.example.com/page2
```

should display a list of the recent posts published on that page.
In my understanding, this means in my urlpatterns I first need to access the pages.urls.py and then have . 
I'm struggling with how to properly construct urls to individual posts from the pages/urls.py and pages/views.py and how to correctly render these urls in the templates. Any suggestions on this issue or whether I should take a completely different approach are highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any code on pages /urls /views?

Comment: I decided to rebuild the pages and blog application because the current blog structure is not suited to achieve the modularity I want. I'll upload my new version shortly.